# iPad doesn't auto rotate to landscape

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have a project where my screen needs to be tested on both landscape and portrait orientations and it needs to happen automatically as I am running some UI test cases for that I use the below code.

```
let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.landscapeRight.rawValue
UIDevice.current.setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")
```

This works fine on iPhone simulator and the simulator turns itself to landscape mode but on iPad simulator doesn't rotate itself

Things I have tried :
Added the below code to

```
UIViewController.attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation()
```

Also didn't  work and checked if the orientation is supported by iPad or not using:

```
self.supportedInterfaceOrientations
```

Which returned 30 (All orientations were supported)

1. If the iPad simulator rotates (physically) at all?
2. If yes am I missing anything?